# How to toggle between two menu items using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 menu items "English" and "Spanish" that currently display on my website.

I am wanting the "Spanish" menu item to be displayed on page load and the "English" menu item to be hidden.

When the "Spanish" menu item is selected I want the "English" menu item to be displayed and the "Spanish" menu item to be hidden. As you can see I am looking for a toggle solution for the two menu items. I don't want to use a dropdown.

My strength is not `if-else` statements and I am hoping someone can help with a solution. I was thinking about getting the menu items by ids?

Here are the 2 menu ids:

`menu-item-4002` and `menu-item-4003`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $LangEs = $("#menu-item-4002");
    var $LangEn = $("#menu-item-4003").hide();

    $("#menu-item-4002").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $LangEn.hide();
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        if(target){
            $LangEn.filter(target).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What kind of transitions did you have in mind ? Also It would be nice to have a working snippet demonstrating your current menu. This can really vary depending on your HTML and the animations you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an element is hidden using `.is(':hidden')`, and show the hidden button, and hide the visible one:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $LangEs = $("#menu-item-4002");
  var $LangEn = $("#menu-item-4003").hide();

  [$LangEs, $LangEn].forEach(function(el) {
    el.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if($LangEn.is(':hidden')) {
        $LangEs.hide();
        $LangEn.show();
      } else {
        $LangEn.hide();
        $LangEs.show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="menu-item-4002">ES</button>
<button id="menu-item-4003">EN</button>
```